# Qt catch pressed key

Tags: c++, qt, paint

i think of to write primitive snake.  i have window where program paints random lines.

but i can't think up how to catch pressed key to change direction of painted line.

[image]

```
class QUpdatingPathIte : public QGraphicsPathItem
{
    void advance(int phase)
    {

        if (phase == 0)
            return;

        int x,y;
        int w,a,s,d;

        char c;
        // 
        // HOW TO    MAKE THIS HERE? (i had done early in console application)
        // but i can't do this in GUI , what should i  do?

        scanf("%c",&c);
        if (c=='w')
        { x=-20; y=0; }
        else if (c=='s')
        { x=20; y=0; }
        else if (c=='a')
        { x=0; y=-20; }
        else if(c=='d')
        { x=0; y=20; }

        QPainterPath p = path();
        p.lineTo(x, y);
        setPath(p);
    }
};

#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "dialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene s;
    QGraphicsView v(&s);

    QUpdatingPathIte item;
    item.setPen(QPen(QColor("black")));
    s.addItem(&item);
    v.show();

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(&s);
    timer->connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &s, SLOT(advance()));
    timer->start(500);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

QGraphicsView inherits from from QWidget because it inherits from QAbstractScrollArea. You should create a custom subclass of QGraphicsView and just override the function keyPressEvent(). Example:

```
class SnakeView : public QGraphicsView
{
protected:
    keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
    {
         // Do something

         // Otherwise pass to the graphics view
         QGraphicsView::keyPressEvent(e)
    }
};
```

Then rather than creating a QGraphicsView object you would create a SnakeView object.

Comment: Another way to do that without subclassing is to install an event filter. See `QObject::installEventFilter()`.

Answer (score 4):

QGraphicsView reimplements [keyPressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#keyPressEvent) and will forward events to the QGraphicsScene. QGraphicsScene supports key presses through its [keyPressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#keyPressEvent) handler. By default the QGraphicsScene will forward that key press to the current QGraphicsItem through its [keyPressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#keyPressEvent) function.

Given the above, what you likely want to do is reimplement the `keyPressEvent` handler in your `QUpdatingPathItem`:

```
void QUpdatingPathItem::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch (event->key()) {
        case Key::Key_A: /* do something useful */; break;
        case Key::Key_S: /* do something useful */; break;
        case Key::Key_W: /* do something useful */; break;
        case Key::Key_D: /* do something useful */; break;
    }
}
```

I couldn't really follow what you were trying to do in your `advance` method, so I can't offer much in the way of a suggested handler.

Besides implementing [QObject::installEventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter), you could also subclass any of QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, or QGraphicsItem and override the keyPressEvent function.

Answer (score 0):

thanks you all. Then I didn't reach my aim. But time went on and I've come to the same problem and now I solved it.

There are right and worth answers but then I wasn't good enough to put them together because no one was full and sufficient. Now I did it so:

```
HEADER FILE "header.h"
class MyGraphicView: public QGraphicsView
{
  Updating *m_update;
 public:
  MyGraphicView(Updating *update);
  void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
};


#include "header.h"
void GraphicView::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
 {
  switch ( event->key())
  {case Qt::Key_Up:
   m_update->move_up();
   break;

 case  Qt::Key_Down:
   m_update->move_down();
   break;

 case  Qt::Key_Left:
 {  m_update->move_right();
   break;
}
 case Qt::Key_Right:
 {  m_update->move_left();
   break;
}
```

}

}

Thanks again!

Comment: I think CD1212's answer is correct (although not all details are spelled out)?

Answer (score -1):

Your choice of `QGraphicsView` isn't very fortunate.

Basically, when you are implementing some custom painted graphical item (the graphic area of the game is this), you should create your own widget and simply implement the `QWidget::keyPressEvent()` method.

Comment: I must disagree. QGraphicsScene & QGraphicsView are very much intended for this type of thing. There are many other ways to do this besides abandoning their provided functionality.