# A slot is called unexpectedly

Tags: c++, qt

I have a push button's event connected to a slot as shown below:

```
myButton = new QPushButton();
myButton->setText("Connect");
myButton->setFocus();
connect(myButton,SIGNAL(released()),this, SLOT(doStuff()));
```

When I run the program, if I right click on the button "Connect", this calls `doStuff()` function as expected.

However this slot is also get called when I press and release the space key. This is not desired as I want to connect another slot to space key pressed event. I don't believe I have any other signals connected to "doStuff". Am I missing something? Why does this happen?

*Edit*:
I'd like some other slot to be called on space key released signal. How can I fix this? By removing the focus?

Comment: Probably you have focus on that button and when you hit space it automatically emits release signal of the button?

Comment: Well, not probably, you've called setFocus()

Comment: @guneykayim Thanks. yes, there is focus, I thought it might be an important detail, that's why I included that in the code sample. But what if I don't want this behavior? should I just remove the focus from the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can basically remove `setFocus()` or you need to implement key pressed event. Take a look at these [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083829/qt-catch-pressed-key), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242065/qt-mainwindow-handle-space-key-press) threads.